# Properties that are objects become null when trying to use SaveChanges (of Entity Framework Core), why is that?

Tags: c#, sql

When I use `_context.SaveChanges()` at the end of my `DataInitializer`, it throws a custom error that I wrote for the setter (code down here) of an object in another object.

```
public Locatie Locatie
{
    get => _locatie;
    set
    {
        if (value is null)
            throw new ArgumentException(Settings.locatieLeeg);
        else
            _locatie = value;
    }
}
```

However, if I get rid of the if statement for null it just goes to the next setter that also checks for null. This leads me to believe that all my subojects of an object are set to null. This wasn't a problem before and now it is, I'm not sure why to be honest. The only changes that I've implemented since then are the fact that I added a new table that is not related to the object with the setter that throws an error.

The output of the console gets stuck here:

Info:

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
Executed DbCommand (52ms) [Parameters=[@p0='?' (Size = 100), @p1='?' (Size = 4000), @p2='?' (Size = 100), @p3='?' (Size = 6), @p4='?' (Size = 100)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
SET NOCOUNT ON;
INSERT INTO [Locatie] ([Gemeente], [Huisnummer], [Land], [Postcode], [Straat])
VALUES (@p0, @p1, @p2, @p3, @p4);

SELECT [LocatieId]
FROM [Locatie]
WHERE @@ROWCOUNT = 1 AND [LocatieId] = scope_identity();
```

info:

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
Executed DbCommand (31ms) [Parameters=[@p5='?' (Size = 320), @p6='?' (DbType = Int32), @p7='?' (Size = 14)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
SET NOCOUNT ON;
INSERT INTO [ContactPagina] ([Email], [LocatieId], [Telefoonnummer])
VALUES (@p5, @p6, @p7);
SELECT [ContactPaginaId]
FROM [ContactPagina]
WHERE @@ROWCOUNT = 1 AND [ContactPaginaId] = scope_identity();
```

Nonetheless, the output seems to change depending of how many `SaveChanges` I use in my `ApplicationDataInitializer`, therefore I thought it'd be interesting to add that class.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using ProjectKiwi.Models.Domain;

namespace ProjectKiwi.Data
{
    public class ApplicationDataInitializer
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _dbContext;
        private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;

        public ApplicationDataInitializer(ApplicationDbContext dbContext, UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
        {
            _dbContext = dbContext;
            _userManager = userManager;
        }

        public async Task InitializeData()
        {
            _dbContext.Database.EnsureDeleted();

            if (_dbContext.Database.EnsureCreated())
            {
                await InitializeUsers();
                _dbContext.SaveChanges();

                #region Contactpagina
                var contactpagina = new ContactPagina("info@bvbr.be", "+32478229952", new Locatie("Lombardstraat" ,"34", "Brussel", "1000", "België"));
                contactpagina.VoegSocialeMediaToe(new SocialeMedia(SocialeMediaType.YouTube, "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OchTO8pQjR0&list=RDOchTO8pQjR0&start_radio=1"));
                contactpagina.VoegSocialeMediaToe(new SocialeMedia(SocialeMediaType.Facebook, "https://www.facebook.com/messages/t/1980502862034183"));
                contactpagina.VoegSocialeMediaToe(new SocialeMedia(SocialeMediaType.LinkedIn, "https://www.linkedin.com/in/ruben-szek%C3%A9r-978027160/"));
                contactpagina.VoegSocialeMediaToe(new SocialeMedia(SocialeMediaType.Twitter, "https://twitter.com/mrnosleep07/status/1106022067059781632?s=21&fbclid=IwAR2420XE-a1luCKC_oUMBcaF2fbNvh0bfygCAYBQvOY0kdB6VNzfC_mpAGI"));
                contactpagina.VoegSocialeMediaToe(new SocialeMedia(SocialeMediaType.Instagram, "https://www.instagram.com/"));
                contactpagina.VoegSocialeMediaToe(new SocialeMedia(SocialeMediaType.Reddit, "https://www.reddit.com/r/W385/comments/bcid0h/beginner_clues_hotcold_locations_determined_with/"));
                _dbContext.ContactPaginas.AddRange(new List<ContactPagina>(){ contactpagina });
                #endregion
                _dbContext.SaveChanges();

                #region Nieuwsartikels
                var artikel1 = new Nieuwsartikel("Probleem op het werk..",
                                                "Inihilit atesequam, conecust voluptati rehenitatur am dit, ilibus mo et ex erferfero doluptium quae prestis quam, es- sed quis aut magnihictur?Bitaturiam, ipit aceptatur, odit, at re cor sim quam fugiandae audis vent quodiati volo omni dolorro cus nonsernate sunt enditatur? Duciendigent mo omnim fuga. Ita se molore");

                var artikel2 = new Nieuwsartikel("Heel goed nieuws!",
                                                "Inihilit atesequam, conecust voluptati rehenitatur am dit, ilibus mo et ex erferfero doluptium quae prestis quam, es- sed quis aut magnihictur?Bitaturiam, ipit aceptatur, odit, at re cor sim quam fugiandae audis vent quodiati volo omni dolorro cus nonsernate sunt enditatur? Duciendigent mo omnim fuga. Ita se molore");

                var artikel3 = new Nieuwsartikel("Nog beter nieuws!",
                                        "Inihilit atesequam, conecust voluptati rehenitatur am dit, ilibus mo et ex erferfero doluptium quae prestis quam, es- sed quis aut magnihictur?Bitaturiam, ipit aceptatur, odit, at re cor sim quam fugiandae audis vent quodiati volo omni dolorro cus nonsernate sunt enditatur? Duciendigent mo omnim fuga. Ita se molore");

                _dbContext.Artikels.AddRange(new List<Nieuwsartikel> { artikel1, artikel2, artikel3 });
                #endregion
                _dbContext.SaveChanges();

                #region Bestuursleden
                var bestuurslid1 = new Bestuurslid("Benoît", "Kohl", BestuursPositie.Bestuurder,"BenoîtKohl.jpg", new SocialeMedia(SocialeMediaType.LinkedIn, "https://www.linkedin.com/in/benoit-kohl-72a53a6/"));

                var bestuurslid2 = new Bestuurslid("Marc-Antoine", "Lemaigre", BestuursPositie.Bestuurder, "Marc-AntoineLemaigre.jpg", new SocialeMedia(SocialeMediaType.LinkedIn, "https://www.linkedin.com/in/marc-antoine-lemaigre-665444b3/"));

                var bestuurslid3 = new Bestuurslid("Luc", "Imbrechts", BestuursPositie.Bestuurder, "LucImbrechts.jpg", new SocialeMedia(SocialeMediaType.LinkedIn, "https://www.linkedin.com/in/luc-imbrechts-24677525/?originalSubdomain=be"));

                var bestuurslid4 = new Bestuurslid("Laurence", "Abeloos", BestuursPositie.Bestuurder, "LaurenceAbeloos.jpg", new SocialeMedia(SocialeMediaType.LinkedIn, "https://www.linkedin.com/in/laurence-abeloos-149260167/"));

                var bestuurslid5 = new Bestuurslid("Denis-Bruno", "Floor", BestuursPositie.Bestuurder, "Denis-BrunoFloor.jpg", new SocialeMedia(SocialeMediaType.LinkedIn, "https://be.linkedin.com/in/denis-bruno-floor-09b45958"));

                var bestuurslid6 = new Bestuurslid("Bart", "Gheysens", BestuursPositie.Bestuurder, "BartGheysens.jpg", new SocialeMedia(SocialeMediaType.LinkedIn, "https://www.linkedin.com/in/bart-gheysens-b459429a/"));

                var bestuurslid7 = new Bestuurslid("Kris", "Lemmens", BestuursPositie.Bestuurder, "KrisLemmens.jpg", new SocialeMedia(SocialeMediaType.LinkedIn, "https://www.linkedin.com/in/kris-lemmens-7671716/"));

                var bestuurslid8 = new Bestuurslid("Catherine", "Sarot", BestuursPositie.Bestuurder, "CatherineSarot.jpg", new SocialeMedia(SocialeMediaType.LinkedIn, "linkedin.com"));

                var bestuurslid9 = new Bestuurslid("Renaud", "Simar", BestuursPositie.Bestuurder, "RenaudSimar.jpg", new SocialeMedia(SocialeMediaType.LinkedIn, "https://www.linkedin.com/company/renaud-simar-avocat/"));

                var bestuurslid10 = new Bestuurslid("Elke", "Van Overwaele", BestuursPositie.Bestuurder, "ElkeVanOverwaele.jpg", new SocialeMedia(SocialeMediaType.LinkedIn, "https://www.linkedin.com/in/elke-van-overwaele-a4639946/"));

                var bestuurslid11 = new Bestuurslid("Francis", "Walschot", BestuursPositie.Bestuurder, "FrancisWalschot.jpg", new SocialeMedia(SocialeMediaType.LinkedIn, "https://www.linkedin.com/in/francis-walschot-98b724115/"));

                _dbContext.Bestuurleden.AddRange(new List < Bestuurslid > { bestuurslid1, bestuurslid2, bestuurslid3, bestuurslid4, bestuurslid5, bestuurslid6, bestuurslid7, bestuurslid8, bestuurslid9, bestuurslid10, bestuurslid11 });
                #endregion
                _dbContext.SaveChanges();

                #region Forumposts
                string BESCHRIJVING = "Inihilit atesequam, conecust voluptati rehenitatur am dit, ilibus mo et ex erferfero doluptium quae prestis quam, es - sed quis aut magnihictur? Bitaturiam, ipit aceptatur, odit, at re cor sim quam fugiandae audis vent quodiati volo omni dolorro cus nonsernate sunt enditatur? Duciendigent mo omnim fuga.";

                Categorie belangrijkCategorie = new Categorie("Heel Belangrijk");
                Categorie seminarieVragenCategorie = new Categorie("Vragen seminarie");
                var forumpost1 = new Forumpost("Hoe word je lid?", BESCHRIJVING, new Deelnemer("Yannick","Olivier", "Yannick.olivier@hotmail.com", new Organisatie("ProjectKiwi", ""), "Werknemer", "yannick.jpg", true), belangrijkCategorie);
                var forumpost2 = new Forumpost("We bestaan sinds..", BESCHRIJVING, new Deelnemer("Jan","Vanleemhuizen", "Ruben.leem@gmail.com", new Organisatie("HoGent", ""), "Werknemer", "jan.jpg", true), belangrijkCategorie);
                var forumpost3 = new Forumpost("Let op de volgende seminaries..", BESCHRIJVING, new Deelnemer("Jan","Van der Steen", "Robbie2@hotmail.com", new Organisatie("Hogent", ""), "Werknemer", "jan.jpg", false), belangrijkCategorie);
                var forumpost4 = new Forumpost("Vragen omtrent presentatie Mr. Leemhuizen", BESCHRIJVING, new Deelnemer("Jan","Jansens", "JanJansens@hotmail.com", new Organisatie("BVBR-ADBC", ""), "Werknemer", "jan.jpg", false), seminarieVragenCategorie);

                forumpost1.VoegCommentToe(new Deelnemer("Yannick", "Olivier", "yann@gmail.com", new Organisatie("ToulousCo", ""), "werknemer", "yannick.jpg", false), 
                    "Maar wat met dat één probleem, dat raakt nooit opgelost.");
                forumpost1.VoegCommentToe(new Deelnemer("Ruben", "Szeker", "rubo@gmail.com", new Organisatie("ToulousCo", ""), "werknemer", "jan.jpg", false), 
                    "Ja dat vind ik ook wel.");

                belangrijkCategorie.VoegForumpostToe(forumpost1);
                belangrijkCategorie.VoegForumpostToe(forumpost2);
                seminarieVragenCategorie.VoegForumpostToe(forumpost3);
                seminarieVragenCategorie.VoegForumpostToe(forumpost4);

                _dbContext.Categories.AddRange(belangrijkCategorie, seminarieVragenCategorie);
                #endregion
                _dbContext.SaveChanges();

                #region Seminaries
                // Eerst sprekers, locaties en datum
                DateTime datumDoorgaat = new DateTime(2019, 5, 12);

                Locatie locatie1 = new Locatie("Moorselbaan", "123", "Aalst", "9300", "België");
                Locatie locatie2 = new Locatie("Erembodegemse straat", "54", "Gent", "7000", "België");

                var spreker1 = new Spreker("Richard", "Van de Welle", "RichardVanDeWelle@outlook.com", null, "Ewa tekst enzo");
                var spreker2 = new Spreker("Roberto", "Drogenbroecke", "Roberto21@outlook.com", null, "Nog wat andere woorden");
                var spreker3 = new Spreker("Ruben", "Szeker", "ruben@outlook.com", null, "Misschien een titel van Hofstade");

                spreker1.VoegTaalToe(Taal.Nederlands);
                spreker1.VoegTaalToe(Taal.Français);
                spreker1.VoegSocialeMediaToe(new SocialeMedia(SocialeMediaType.Facebook,"facebook.be"));
                spreker2.VoegTaalToe(Taal.Nederlands);
                spreker3.VoegTaalToe(Taal.Français);

                // Dan de seminaries
                var seminarie1 = new Seminarie(datumDoorgaat.Date.AddDays(5), 30.00, 40.00, "", 50, "Investeren",
                    "Hoe doe je een investering. Begin met een sterke aanpak. Dit is nog wat placeholder tekst via een lange zin. ",
                    locatie1, new TimeSpan(18, 0, 0), new TimeSpan(20, 0, 0));
                seminarie1.VoegSprekerToe(spreker1);
                seminarie1.VoegSprekerToe(spreker2);
                seminarie1.Talen.Add(Taal.Nederlands);

                var seminarie2 = new Seminarie(datumDoorgaat.Date.AddMonths(2), 30.00, 40.00, "", 50, "Aandelen kopen", 
                    BESCHRIJVING.Substring(0, 70), locatie2, new TimeSpan(15, 0, 0), new TimeSpan(18, 30, 0));
                seminarie2.VoegSprekerToe(spreker3);

                var seminarie3 = new Seminarie(datumDoorgaat.Date.AddDays(9), 30.00, 40.00, "", 50, "Investeren", 
                    BESCHRIJVING.Substring(0,50), locatie1, new TimeSpan(9, 30, 0), new TimeSpan(12, 30, 0));
                seminarie3.VoegSprekerToe(spreker2);

                var seminaries = new List<Seminarie> { seminarie1, seminarie2, seminarie3};
                _dbContext.Seminaries.AddRange(seminaries);
                #endregion
                _dbContext.SaveChanges();

                #region Deelnemers
                var deelnemer1 = new Deelnemer("Souhaib", "Akrouchi", "souhaib.akrouchi@outlook.com", new Organisatie("Hogent", ""), "werknemer", "", true);
                var deelnemer2 = new Deelnemer("Yannick", "Olivier", "yannick@outlook.com", new Organisatie("Hogent", ""), "werknemer", "", true);
                var deelnemer3 = new Deelnemer("Ruben", "Szeker", "ruben@outlook.com", new Organisatie("Hogent", ""), "werknemer", "", true);

                var persoon1 = new Deelnemer("Yannick", "Olivier",
                "yannick.olivier@outlook.com", new Organisatie("Hogent", ""),
                "Student", "yannick.jpg", true);

                var persoon2 = new Deelnemer("Jan", "Depratere",
                "jan.depratere@outlook.com", new Organisatie("LawForce", ""),
                "Advocaat", "jan.jpg", true);

                var deelnemers = new List<Deelnemer> { deelnemer1, deelnemer2, deelnemer3,
                    persoon1, persoon2 };
                _dbContext.Deelnemers.AddRange(deelnemers);
                #endregion
                _dbContext.SaveChanges();
            }

        }


        private async Task InitializeUsers()
        {
            ApplicationUser user = new ApplicationUser {
                UserName =  "yannick.olivier@outlook.com",
                Email = "yannick.olivier@outlook.com" };
            await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, "P@ssword11");
            await _userManager.AddClaimAsync(user, new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "klant"));

            var eMailAddress = "jan.depratere@outlook.com";
            user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = eMailAddress, Email = eMailAddress };
            await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, "P@ssword11");
            await _userManager.AddClaimAsync(user, new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "administrator"));
        }
    }
}
```

Any theories?

EDIT:

ANSWER: I somehow managed to fix it by reprogramming and cleaning up code in my repositories, mappers, applicationdatainitializer etc. but I'm still not sure what caused it.

Comment: Initialize methods are part of the class constructor and some objects may null.  Instead put the code in the Load() method after all the objects are constructed.

Comment: What code should I put there? I'm not 100% following. I'm also not sure what you mean with the "Load()" method, I have no such method in my project.

Comment: Most classes that have an Initialize also have a Load() Event.  See  msdn : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.frameworkelement.loaded?view=netframework-4.8